# Ionic menu in a specific page that let interactibility on page

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, mobile, ionic4

/!\ english is not my natural language/!\

Their is the context:
On 2 page of my app, their is a map part (where I use leaflet), and a menu for showing data to the user. For now the menus are in my `app.composent.html` because, when I wanted to put them on the conserned page, I couldn't interact with the map part.
But the problem is that will I'll show specific data, it could be better to have the "show data" menu on the conserned page and not on `app.composent.html`

Did you know a solution to have my menu on the good html component that hollow me to interact with the rest of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to doing it:
Not using a menu. And use a custom component (or a div) that you show or hide like a menu via CSS